# Implementing Swift's NSObjectProtocol's hash generates warnings in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

The Swift protocol `NSObjectProtocol` defines `hash` as a property returning an `Int`. The Objective-C protocol `NSObject` defines `hash` as a property of type `NSUInteger`.

Since `NSUInteger` is an unsigned integer, and `Int` is a signed integer, these types are not compatible. As a result, the generated Objective-C header for any Swift object conforming to `NSObjectProtocol` generates warnings of the form:

> "Property type 'NSInteger" (aka 'int') is incompatible with type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int') inherited from 'NSObject'.

Is there a way to define a Swift object so that it does not produce these warnings? (As goes without saying, I do not want to manually tweak the generated headers with pragmas.)

Separately, is hash even required? API documentation says it's available up to iOS7.1, but it's not marked as optional, so I'm confused.

Comment: "The Objective-C protocol NSObject defines hash as a method returning an NSUInteger." Actually in the iOS 8 SDK it is declared as a property of type `NSUInteger`